# Reverse offsetof / Get name of element by offset

Tags: c++, c, assembly

Given the offset of an element in a C++ struct, how can I find its name/type without manual counting? This would be especially useful when decoding ASM code where such offsets are regularly used. Ideally the tool would parse a C(++) header file and then give the answer from that. Thanks for any pointers :)

Comment: Are you asking for a tool that *guesses*?  Changing the compiler, target machine, build parameters, or compiler directives in entirely different files could change which element is at a particular offset.

Comment: Why not roll your own? Re-build it along with you are working on, using the same build parameters to make sure it does not cheat on you... ;-)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow. But yes, @DrewDormann, a tool that guesses may work. I wrote my own disassembler and integrated reading a simplified version of structs. I'm sure it only works for the one version of the original compiler that got used.

Comment: @Drew Dormann: In my particular use case, it would be applied to some Win32 API code where I would use this mostly for simple vtables filled with pointers. There the element position is just the offset divided by four bytes (on x86). It's easy to calculate by hand, but nevertheless annoying. For the general case, I imagine the tool would be integrated into the compiler.

Comment: Without Type Introspection (Runtime Type Information ..) this is hopeless. Typeinfo is gone runtime. If your language provides typeinfo via RTI deduct the offset so you have the pointer to struct, and use the appropriate library function to get a pointer to its RTI. Then walk the RTI till the offset and you have the fieldname.

Comment: You may parse preprocessor results and dynamically create a program that prints interesting struct-field-to-offset maps (i.e. generate rtti) using the same compiler flags and then link it to your runtimes. A lot of work though.

Answer (score 1):

One such tool might be the compiler itself (using the same ABI-relevant flags as used to generate the code).  Create a small program which includes the header file, then prints the result of `offsetof`applied to each struct's members.  You'll then have a suitable look-up table which you could refer to manually, or use as input to another tool you might write.

It may be possible (depending on the complexity of the headers) to auto-generate the program above (you'll probably want to run the header through the C preprocessor first, to expand macros and select the correct branch of conditionals).